# How to get description of a Salesforce Object using api or query in Mulesoft?

Tags: salesforce, mule, mulesoft, mule4

I have requirement where I need to retrieve description of a Salesforce Object (Standard or Custom) in Mulesoft. eg In the below image the description is "This is the TEST Object".

1. I have tried **describe sObject** but it does not returns this field.
2. Enabling **Tooling API** definitely returns this in Salesforce but again I think it is not achievable in Mulesoft to use this description for further automation.

Any other approach or API or Query would help me

[image: TestObject]

Answer (score 2):

Tooling API should be just a slightly different endpoint. You pass the session id same way, as `Authorization Bearer ....` header.

You send normal queries to `/services/data/v54.0/query?q=select+id,+name+from+account+limit+10`

and tooling queries to `/services/data/v54.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+QualifiedApiName+FROM+EntityDefinition+LIMIT+10`

So this tooling api query should be a good start

```
SELECT DeveloperName, QualifiedApiName, Description
FROM EntityDefinition
WHERE Description != null
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @eyescream. This definitely works but is there any alternative to tooling api for retrieving description? It seems We have less privileges to generate token for using api.

Comment: Hm, evil. privileges you say... how exactly does Mule connect? Can you control the "connected app" and check the OAuth2 scopes? Maybe it needs "full" or maybe your connecting user's profile/permission set needs "Customize Application" for the tooling api to be available.

Comment: You probably could pull it off by calling Metadata API retrieve of the sobject's definition but that sounds bit custom and overkill. Ever worked with "package.xml" stuff? If not you personally - ask Salesforce developer if you have any in the team. Somebody who used sfdx / vscode / eclipse or "migration tool" in the past.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I actually don't know how to use the package.xml but after doing some research I got some idea regarding how it will be useful. It actually returns description of object as I noticed it in workbench but again seems complicate to replicate the same in mulesoft . Please have a look at this followup question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72211096/retrieve-metadata-connector-resulting-in-error-unable-to-parse-the-unpackaged