# Retrieve Metadata connector resulting in error - Unable to parse the unpackaged stream

Tags: salesforce, mule, mulesoft

Based on the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72198348/12870513) I am trying to use **retrieve metadata** connector in Mulesoft to achieve the description of an Object.

1. Created a **package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>54.0</version>
</Package>
```

2. [Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/9.8/salesforce-connector-reference#parameters-85) suggests that in order to use `Unpackaged` field the format should be `Binary`. Hence I read the package.xml file and then converted it to Binary format using this dwl

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
import dw::Crypto
---
Crypto::hashWith(write(payload,"application/xml"),'MD5')
```

Reference: [Object-Binary](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00005Wan0OSAR/how-to-generate-binary-from-object)

3. Below is what I configured in the connector

[image: RetrieveMetadataConfig]

**Retrieve Metadata Connector Config**

```
<salesforce:retrieve-metadata doc:name="Retrieve metadata" doc:id="d2aa6e13-3012-4e53-a448-3c00f5058f55" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" unpackaged="#[payload]" />
```

This results in the below stack trace

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Unable to parse the unpackaged stream
Element               : sf-testFlow/processors/2 @ sf-test:sf-test.xml:74 (Retrieve metadata)
Element DSL           : <salesforce:retrieve-metadata doc:name="Retrieve metadata" doc:id="d2aa6e13-3012-4e53-a448-3c00f5058f55" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" unpackaged="#[payload]"></salesforce:retrieve-metadata>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
FlowStack             : at sf-testFlow(sf-testFlow/processors/2 @ sf-test:sf-test.xml:74 (Retrieve metadata))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Not sure the connector expects this type of format? or whether this approach is wrong?

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Please add the XML of the operation to your question instead of the screenshot of the UI of it.

Comment: @aled I added the connector config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not converting the XML to binary, you are digitally hashing it, which makes it impossible to recover the original content. Basically it is encrypting the content and throwing away the key.

Have you tried instead the `<salesforce:read-metadata>` operation? Reference https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.11/salesforce-connector-reference#ReadMetadata

Example:

```
            <salesforce:read-metadata type="CustomObject" config-ref="config">
                <salesforce:full-names><![CDATA[#[["Lead"]]]]></salesforce:full-names>
            </salesforce:read-metadata>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right path. Just want to confirm we can only get description of a Custom Object but not Standard object right? Since standard object properties are not editable ?or do you think it is possible to extract description of Standard Object?

Comment: You can get standard objects too but you need to spell them out, `*` doesn't cover them. `<types><members>Account</members><members>Contact</members><members>User</members><members>*</members><name>CustomObject</name></types>` . Check out https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/package-xml/package-xml-adventure and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based_zip_file.htm "For many metadata types, you can replace the value in members with the wildcard character * (asterisk) instead of listing each member separately"